# Primero post ¿Como puede tener el numero del dia?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

estoy usando datepicker de jquery y quisiera saber como puedo tener el numero del dia por ejemplo: lunes es 1, martes es 2, miercoles es 3 etc
y que en el console.log imprima ese numero, gracias por su atencion

les dejo abajo mi codigo

```
function seleccionarveterinarioinfo(id_veterinarioinfo) {
    $('#id_vetinfo').val(id_veterinarioinfo);
    $('#id_vi').val(id_veterinarioinfo);
    console.log(id_veterinarioinfo);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?= base_url('Cliente_controller/fechas_ocupadas') ?>",
        data: {
            id_v: id_veterinarioinfo
        },
        success: function(output) {
            console.log(output);
            $(function() {
                $('#date').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
            });

            function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                return [output.indexOf(string) == -1];
            }
            $(function() {
                $("#date").datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
                    changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
                    minDate: 0
                });
            });
        },
        error: (jqxhr) => {
            console.log(jqxhr.responseJSON);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa el evento `change` y el método `getDate` del datepicker, y el método `getDay` de [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
$("#date").change(function () {
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // retorna un objeto Date
    var day = date.getDay(); // domingo es 0, sábado es 6
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono correctamente